# Apache with 503 Error and laggs

Tags: php, apache

I've noticed that sometimes a page from a customer totally laggy at all or nothing builds (Error 503 appears), WHILE other side continue to run the admin interface also is still online.

My provider told me that by the command "top" I could find out which customer is.

I have now also been found and which user / WEB now causes these problems.

In the "default-error.log" of Apache2 I now have found the following entries:

```
Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: https://XXX.in/index.php?rulesAgree=1&pa...n=register

(104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: https://XXX.in/index.php?rulesAgree=1&pa...n=register

SIGUSR1 received. Doing graceful restart

Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.6 mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o configured -- resuming normal operations

mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /var/www/fcgi/XXX.in/php5-fcgi-starter, referer: https://XXX.in/index.php?page=Index
```

Now I think to myself sometimes what is wrong with the / etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid_imscp.conf and there are perhaps not enough values​​. The same for the php5-fcgi-starter.

**fcgid_imscp.conf currently provides the following content:**

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
AddHandler fcgid-script .php .php5
SocketPath /var/lib/apache2/fcgid/sock
IdleTimeout 600
IdleScanInterval 120
BusyTimeout 300
BusyScanInterval 120
ErrorScanInterval 3
ZombieScanInterval 3
ProcessLifeTime 900
SpawnScoreUpLimit 10
SpawnScore 1
TerminationScore 2
MaxProcessCount 200
DefaultMaxClassProcessCount 10
DefaultMinClassProcessCount 1
IPCCommTimeout 900
MaxRequestsPerProcess 500
MaxRequestLen 104857600
</IfModule>
```

**The php5-fcgi-starter Content:**

```
#!/bin/sh

umask 022

PHPRC="/var/www/fcgi/XXX.in/php5/"
export PHPRC

TMPDIR="/var/www/virtual/XXX.in/phptmp"
export TMPDIR

PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=2
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN

exec /usr/bin/php5-cgi
```

Do you think it is up to the values ​​of these files? Can you help me? Otherwise, the website is running really well.

I use IMSCP as ISP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is better placed at Server Fault

Comment: Anybody can help me with my Issue?